# Visual Studio Code - Change the colour of disabled sideBar items

Tags: visual-studio-code, vs-color-theme-editor

I want to change the colour of disabled sideBar-items (see picture). Which property can I use to change that in the settings.json? I know that you use `sideBar.foreground` to edit the active sideBar-items but I don't know how to do that for the deactivated ones.

[image: The disabled sideBar-Item]

Comment: Maybe try `list.deemphasizedForeground`.

Comment: `list.demphasizedForeground` does not work

Answer (score 1):

I imagine those are ignored files:

```js
"gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a theme for the icons.
Go to extensions and search for  material icon theme.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.

I marked the desired object in the picture.